# Спаситель и спасатель

Tags: семантика, лексика

В чем разница между словами "спаситель" (не в христианском смысле) и "спасатель"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**СпасИтель**
1. Тот, кто спас, спасёт кого-либо.
2. [с прописной буквы] В христианстве:
 искупитель грехов человечества; одно из имён Иисуса Христа.

**СпасАтель**
1. Специалист по спасательным работам.
2. Спасательное судно.

В общем, спаситель может не быть спасателем (по специальности), спасителем можно оказаться совершенно случайно. А вот у спасателя в этом отношении есть обязательства: он спасает по роду своей деятельности.

Answer (score 0):

"Спаситель" - это ситуация, обычно разовая. Петя Машу спас (денег одолжил, машину починил, бабку через улицу перевел) - Петя машин спаситель. Обычно - иронически.
Спасатель - это професиия, род занятий. Он может за всю жизнь лично никого не спасти, только числиться сторожем при спасательной станции или коком на спасательном судне.